# Is there a physical circumstance where the flow of a system changes from a nodal source/sink to a saddle?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, differential-equations

Phase portraits for sinks can often like eddies in water, so I would assume there is some fluid or aerodynamic system where these curves appear. But, the only difference between a saddle and a nodal source/sink is that one eigenvalue is positive, so theoretically there could be a situation where with one eigenvalue fixed, the other changes from something like -0.01 to +0.01. Are there any dynamic systems that have completely changing types of flows like that in real-time?

Comment: Suppose you have a bathroom sink. Water flows to the center and down the drain. Suppose the sink is 0.01 m deep. Now change the curvature in the x direction, but leave the y direction fixed. Make x flat, and then curved upward 0.01 m.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for incompressible [extensional flow](https://www.sharcnet.ca/Software/Ansys/16.2.3/en-us/help/poly_pm/pm_ug_sec_rheo_steady_ext.html) whose strain rate tensor has at least one positive and at least one negative eigenvalue (corresponding to stretching and compression respectively) so as to satisfy continuity.

Comment: Page wouldn't load though.

Comment: It is loading correctly in my chrome browser. Here's the link: https://www.sharcnet.ca/Software/Ansys/16.2.3/en-us/help/poly_pm/pm_ug_sec_rheo_steady_ext.html